# Parallel Visible JPanels on JFame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So, I'm rewriting a program I wrote and I realised that the following would really help me out: can I get get two JPanels parallel (vertically) to each other, both of which are visible at once within the same jFrame. I'd like the upper panel to be much shorter (but equally wide, like a toolbar) compared to the lower one. Is this possible? And if so, can I get it so that I can change the lower panel to a different one (displaying different data) when the user desires (without affecting the upper panel)?

So basically what I'm asking is:

- Can I have two JPanels on one JFrame; one starts where the other ends; and both visible?
- Can I switch between a number of lower panels (as per user request) and can it be done efficiently (there is quite a bit going on on each panel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like the upper panel to be much shorter (but equally wide, like a toolbar) compared to the lower one. Is this possible?

Yes. Put them both in a JPanel that uses BorderLayout, and place the top JPanel in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position, and the lower JPanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position.

> And if so, can I get it so that I can change the lower panel to a different one (displaying different data) when the user desires (without affecting the upper panel)?

If you want to swap "views" in the lower region, then consider having the lower JPanel use a CardLayout, give it several "card" JPanels, and then swap the card JPanels that it displays using the methods of the CardLayout.

**Edit**:  Don't forget to study the [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more on this.

Comment: @user1875290: you're welcome. Please check out the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can add more JPanels on JFrame like [that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html). And you should look layouts like gridbaglayout,boxlayout,flowlayout...